# How to unload X server / switch to command line and back on the fly

Tags: linux, rhel, x11

I often need UI to configure my server, even to run Eclipse and work there, but in "production" i want to have only mandatory things running - just command-line and no UI.

If I'm running UI on Linux how can I easily unload all UI and just use command-line. Do I have to reboot to do something like that? Can I switch back?

I'm using RHEL 7 and I access it via iLO (so far not installed any remote access).

Comment: i've found that executing `telinit 3` for terminal and `telinit 5` for gui session works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You *should* log out, and then log in to a terminal-only environment. But if you don't care about preserving the current state of the GUI environment you can instantly kill X windows with `Ctrl-Alt-Backspace`. I'm not very familiar with the modern Red Hat environment, but I assume that when X is killed it's restarted and you are then presented with the graphical login dialog. If that dialog doesn't give you an option for a terminal-only login, try `Ctrl-Alt-F1` (or some other low function key if F1 doesn't work), which should get you straight to a terminal login.

When you are in GUI mode you can use those same `Ctrl-Alt-Fn` sequences to quickly switch between sessions. The usual X windows convention puts the GUI session at `Ctrl-Alt-F7`, the other sessions are normally terminal-only.